# TortoiseSVN - how to update a previous revision without removing all current ones?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am an SVN newbie so I apologize if I don't know the correct terminology or if this is a simple question.

I have a production server running revision 231 and a staging server running revision 238. I am currently making all sorts of changes in revision 238 which are not yet ready to go live.

However, the client has a quick change that needs to be made ASAP to the production server (running revision 231). I thought I could just update my local copy to revision 231, make the change, commit it, launch the new revision on my production server, then go back to making my changes to revision 238.

However, doesn't seem to like that. Tortoise keeps failing the commit telling me things are in conflict. I have tried making my head revision 231 but couldn't get that to stick either.

Reading through all of the help files, everything that says "revert" and "undo" scare me because I do not wish to lose the more current revisions. I just need to touch that old one for a sec then go back to working on my more current files.

How can this be accomplished? Or even just help me with what is the correct terminology for doing what I am wanting to do so I know what to search the TortoiseSVN help for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all previous answers are somehow *not perfect*

- save you current changes (**unrelated** to hotfix) and commit as 239 in trunk
- update WC to rev. 231 `svn up -r 231`
- Make hotfix changes, save in WC
- in TSVN in WC-root select "Branch/tag" and define new branch in repository. Don't select "Swith to" checkbox
- Commit changes into branch into rev.240
- export this revision as replacement for LIVE
- return back to 239 in trunk, merge your branch into trunk
- continue your work

Comment: Wow - love the detailed steps. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be scared from doing "revert", you working in local copy!! you code is safe in the svn server.
before you do revert try the "clean" function. then try to do revert and then do Update to last version.
If you are still afraid I suggest you to make a new "Working copy" and to see that noting happens.

Answer (score 0):

Create a branch from revision 231 (call it an emergency prod bug fix). Commit your fix to this branch. That commit will get revision 239, but don't worry. SVN revisions are absolute, and your code in your present branch that contains 231 and 238 (I will assume it is trunk) is unaffected by your new prod bug fix branch and the commit of revision 239.

Release your fix from the prod bug fix branch.

Then merge prod fix branch to trunk. Your code for the emergency bug fix will now be in your main branch.  Commit the merge, which will get a subversion revision 240.

Comment: @LazyBadger I had fat-fingered my answer, was typing on iPad.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I meant to say "Create a branch from revision 231 ..." as my first sentence.  With that correction, the rest of my answer I believe is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! This got me moving in the right direction and I think I got it now. Really appreciate your time!